# How can I make my actor not die?

Tags: akka.net

I'm learning Akka.net. I've set up a running test where I'm running an actor locally, and remotely over to another actor on a VM in Azure.

The problem is, after I'm done and close the application locally the remote actor also goes down.

"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

What I need the remote actor to is just to accept the termination, and wait for the next connection from the actor running locally. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating actors using [remote deployment](http://getakka.net/docs/remoting/deployment), then actor will always be stopped, once it's parent will be die (due to actor system shutdown). In this case, while child is living on another machine, it's still a child of local actor. This is a natural part of actor system lifecycle - children cannot live without their parents.

If you're interested with having your actors scattered among cluster nodes and make them rebalanced/recreated automatically, you may take a look at [Akka.Cluster.Sharding](http://getakka.net/docs/clustering/cluster-sharding) plugin. Keep in mind, that while a lot easier, this solution is also a more complex and slower solution than standard akka actors. Make sure you really need those features.

Comment: I second this answer - what you are describing is by design. If the parent/supervisor goes away, so does the child.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an actor to continue to live on then you cannot use remote deployment, you should be creating a service that contains the actor and interact with it using some form of remote technology such as wcf, rest and/or web services.

If you want an actor to exist waiting for work, then I suggest that you look into a different product - try nServiceBus from Particular.net, we use it this way and are very happy with it. It is essentially the actor model listening to a persistent queue.